# How can i make standalone .exe file using node-webkit?

Tags: node-webkit, nw.js

I'm developed window application from node-webkit, and I make it to .exe file.

i try

```
copy /b nw.exe+myapp.nw
```

and i try to build use nw-builder but it same result.

To perform this .exe file, it need some files(nw.pak, some Dlls).
I want to excute this exe file standalone.

Please let me know any method to excute .exe file standalone

[UPDATE]

I solved this issue.

i found packaging program Enigma Vitual Box and this program help packaging .exe file, nw.pak and other files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Inno Script App to make an installer for the .exe file. I do use it and it makes sense.